# Alternatives to deprecated Webpack's i18n plugin and loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, internationalization

I'm working on a TypeScript project that needs to load translations from `.json` files, the intention is to have a single language file per country. Example: `en.json`, `es.json`.

Then I should to be able to use the translations inside `.ts` files with some function like `__('red')` or as other extensions offer.

Then the final compiled `.js` files should contain all translations to switch the language on "real-time".

The content of the json files could be something like:

*es.json*

```
{
    "colors": {
        "red": "rojo",
        "blue": "blue"
    }
}
```

It seems that the current recommended (on the documentation) i18n loader and plugin for Webpack are deprecated:

- Plugin: [I18nWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/i18n-webpack-plugin)
- Loader: [I18nLoader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/i18n-loader)

I want to know if is safe to use this extensions or there are some available options out there for my case, I tried [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) and [i18next-loader](https://github.com/alienfast/i18next-loader) but it doesn't seem to work on my current setup, it seems to be something related to how modules import process work. So maybe another lightweight alternatives that support Webpack + TypeScipt could solve this issue.

This is my current package.json dependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "i18next": "^19.1.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^16.0.8",
    "uniq": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@alienfast/i18next-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?
[@zainulbr/i18n-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zainulbr/i18n-webpack-plugin)

This is forked from the original `i18n-webpack-plugin` and fixed to support `webpack5`.

The usage is still same with the original unmaintained repository.

Comment: It's nice to know that people can revive projects!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [webpack-localize-assets-plugin](https://github.com/privatenumber/webpack-localize-assets-plugin)?

It has Webpack 5 support and has a few advantages over the deprecated i18n-webpack-plugin:

- first-class support for multiple locales
- able to read locales from JSON path so you can watch and rebuild on change
- able to report unused string keys